# ¿Cómo saber que opción en un radioButton fue elegida y usarlo en un IF?

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones

Tengo un problema con un radio en **html**, quiero extraer lo que se escogió para usarlo en un `if`, todo esto lo hago con **javascript** para extraer el valor

```js
// ese es el codigo del radiobutton y despues trato con esto para extraer el valor de lo que se selecciono
        

    verificado = $('input[name="rad"]:checked').val();
    if (verificado==55) {
        var RecomenD="opcion SI";
        document.getElementById("rec").innerHTML=RecomenD;
    }
    else if (verificado==0) {
        var RecomenD="opcion NO";
        document.getElementById("rec").innerHTML=RecomenD;
    }
```

```html
       <form id="myform">
           <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="radOverclock" value="55" disabled> SI
           <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="radOverclock" value="0"checked disabled> NO
       </form>
```

Dependiendo de esto, mando un texto a un `<div>` que tengo pero no sirve esto que realicé.
Espero me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias por leer esto.

Comment: Al parecer tu código está incompleto, porque deberías verificar el valor del radio dentro de una función, probablemente al hacer clic en cada una de las opciones.

Comment: Saludos. Cambia `$('input[name="rad"]:checked').val()` por `$('input[name="radOverclock"]:checked').val()`; cuando uses esa forma de agrupar toma ciertamente el `name` el detalle que tenias es que pones el `id` en vez del name.

Answer (score 1):

Observaciones:

- Dado el contexto de tu ejercicio no requieres de *JQuery* para la selección de elementos
- Tratas de evaluar lo que el usuario eligió, pero tu selector te esta limitando a solamente aquellos inputs que tienen el atributo `checked` por lo cual el primero queda descartado y no podrás hacer la condición
- Como observación **mas que evaluar el atributo value puedes evaluar si el `input` esta checado o no y en función de eso indicarle que opción le toca**
- Para no agregar mas a tu código podemos hacer uso de `querySelectorAll` para recoger a todos los elementos cuyo name sea uno en específico
- Una vez que tenemos una lista de nodos de todos aquellos que tienen el mismo name entonces podemos usar esa misma variable para el condicional, solo indicando el índice de cada uno de los 2 elementos que deseamos evaluar

Propuesta:

```html
    <form id="myform">
      <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="radOverclock" value="55" disabled> SI
      <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="radOverclock" value="0"checked disabled> NO
    </form>
    <div id="rec"></div>
    <script>
      let seleccion = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=radOverclock]');
      let muestra   = document.getElementById('rec');
      
      if (seleccion[0].checked) {
        muestra.innerText = 'Opción SI';
      } else if (seleccion[1].checked) {
        muestra.innerText = 'Opción NO';
      } else {
        muestra.innerText = 'Ninguna opción elegida';
      }
      
    </script>
```

Aquí el mismo script si modificas y colocas que aparezca desde el inicio la opción SI

```html
    <form id="myform">
      <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="radOverclock" value="55" checked disabled> SI
      <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="radOverclock" value="0" disabled> NO
    </form>
    <div id="rec"></div>
    <script>
      let seleccion = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=radOverclock]');
      let muestra   = document.getElementById('rec');
      
      if (seleccion[0].checked) {
        muestra.innerText = 'Opción SI';
      } else if (seleccion[1].checked) {
        muestra.innerText = 'Opción NO';
      } else {
        muestra.innerText = 'Ninguna opción elegida';
      }
      
    </script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @BetaM me sirvió tu respuesta pero tengo una duda ya que cuando hago el cambio de el  "no" a un "si" (ya que tengo que por defecto que inicie seleccionado la opción no) ya no se actualiza el texto, solo funciona una vez.

Comment: Deja reviso y te actualizo la solución

Comment: @Franciscoac algo debes estar haciendo mal, por que acabo de copiar el código y: quitarle al segundo input el checked y ponerselo al primero y si actualiza mostrandome la opción de SI